# C++ Finding the minimum quotient from two different integer arrays of the same size

Tags: c++, arrays, minimum

I have 2 different arrays numerator[ ], and denominator[ ] and int size which is 9.  They both consist of 9 different integers, and I need to find the lowest quotient  of 2 ints 
(the percentage - (numerator[ ])/(denominator[ ]) ) in the two arrays.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Pairwise, like n[0]/d[0] then n[1]/d[1], or every combination?

Comment: pair wise, not every combination.  I haven't really tried anything yet. I am having difficulty figuring out how to approach this.

Comment: Do you want an `int` or `double` representation of the quotient, or just knowledge of which pair yields the lowest value? For example, would looping through the arrays and dividing each pair solve the problem, or do you need to know if `a / b` is less than `c / d` without actually dividing them?

Comment: I downvoted you for not giving a clear enough question at the outset (causing one answerer to work extra hard) and also not attempting the very first steps of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to return the percentage or the quotient(with no remainder)?
Following code returns the percentage. Change double to int, if you want the quotient.

```
#include<limits>
double lowestQuotient(const int *numerator, const int *denominator)
{
  double min=DBL_MAX;
  double quotient;
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if (denominator[i]==0)
      continue;
  quotient = (double)numerator [i]/denominator [i];
  if (i==0 || quotient<min)
     min=quotient;
}
return min;

}
```

Comment: You're missing some `static_cast<double>()`s in there.

Comment: Good answer. Feedback: declare your function signature as `double lowestQuotient(int* numerator, int* denominator)`

Comment: Don't forget to check if `demoniator[i] == 0` before attempting to do the division operation.

Comment: @selbie I was thinking of using that initially. Is that because we want to avoid passing by value?

Comment: Arrays are never passed by value.  An array degrades to a pointer when passed to a function. So declaring the function as taking pointer parameters instead of array parameters doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yeah I wanted it to return the percentage.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Sosa I made the parameters const since we are not modifying the arrays

Comment: You should initialize `min` to something (maybe DBL_MAX) for the edge case of when all the items in the denominator array are `0`.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: This answer was written before the problem statement was changed to clarify that the intention was not to compare every combination, but instead to only take pair-wise quotients. That simplifies the problem quite a bit and makes my lengthy solution here overkill. This was also written before a solution involving floating point values was indicated; I assumed that the questioner was interested in the mathematical definition of the quotient of two integers, which is itself necessarily an integer. All the same I'll leave this here for posterity...*

*Edit 2: Fixed the compilation error -- thanks James Root for pointing out the error.*

This is a math problem first and a programming problem second.

The naive implementation is to compute every combination of numerators from the first array divided by denominators from the second array, track the minimum quotient as we go, and compute the result.

This would look something like the following:

```
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

int minimum_quotient(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    int minimum = INT_MAX; // minimum quotient
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            if (denominator[j] != 0) // avoid division by 0
                minimum = std::min(minimum, numerator[i] / denominator[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

With `size` being a known, small number, this should be sufficient. However, if we are concerned about the case in which `size` becomes very large, we may want to avoid the above written solution, which scales proportionate to the square of the size of the input.

Here is an idea for a solution that scales better with larger sizes. Specifically it scales linearly with the size of the input. We can take advantage of the following facts:

If the numerators and denominators both have the same sign, then the smallest quotient will be from the numerator with the smallest absolute value and the denominator with the largest absolute value.

If the numerators and denominators have opposite signs, then the opposite is true: for the smallest quotient we want the numerator with the largest absolute value and the denominator with the smallest absolute value.

We can iterate through both lists once, accumulating the largest and smallest numerators and denominators, and then compare these at the end to find the smallest quotient:

```
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

int minimum_quotient(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    int min_num = INT_MAX, min_den = INT_MAX;
    int max_num = INT_MIN, max_den = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        min_num = std::min(min_num, numerator[i]);
        max_num = std::max(max_num, numerator[i]);
        min_den = std::min(min_den, denominator[i]);
        max_den = std::max(max_den, denominator[i]);
    }
    int minimum = INT_MAX;
    if (min_den != 0)
    {
        minimum = std::min(minimum, min_num / min_den);
        minimum = std::min(minimum, max_num / min_den);
    }
    if (max_den != 0)
    {
        minimum = std::min(minimum, min_num / max_den);
        minimum = std::min(minimum, max_num / max_den);
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: Nice effort.  It is pretty wasteful to revise an answer for a simpler problem than the one stated at the outset.

Comment: Even though this was already answered, I thank you very much for your answer.  It was very insightful and helped me understand the whole concept of this a lot better!  Thank you again!